# How to trick WoW to play from network drive / NAS?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, windows-7, networking

I remember that some time before I could play World Of Warcraft from a network drive.

However now with client for WoD datadisk, I get error pop-up saying "The CAS system was unable to initialize: ClientHandler: initialization error: failed to create storage component" and then 3 errors - most notably - "Unsupported drive. Type: 2 Path: data/data/shmem".

The client works fine when used anywhere else localy.

I do understand every issue when running WoW from network drive - I have my own reason to use it that way... so please do not suggest moving WoW elsewhere. Also similary I found many threads but from years before WoD release - so there is not point in posting them :-)

Can this .exe be tricked to think it is actually running from a local hard-drive/usb-external ?

Using: Windows 7

## Before downvoting, please, read comments and possibly provide valid argument that is not disproved. Don't use downvote button based on pre-judicial approach :-)

Comment: Unsupported drive should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: @Frank not completely, since NAS used to work in the past, until they changed their data structure with Warlords of Draenor. Also OP wants to know a workaround and not the reason for that error.

Comment: Exactly as @dly is saying ... I am not complete idiot ;-)

Comment: @MichaelHampton that is just not true, previous WoW clients worked just fine - **don't forget, WoW is ran mainly from RAM** ... so basically it just takes significant time to LOAD, but not to run, and I play low graphics anyway :-)

Comment: I have good experience playing from a drive that goes through USB that has lower speed than the network path... #mirror

Answer (score 3):

there is a way in windows to run wow but its clunky. you can go into disk management and create a virtual hard drive on the NAS and put wow in it. after wow is on the virtual hard drive you can mount it in disk management and the game will run fine. its clunky but it works.

Answer (score 1):

They indeed stopped supporting network drives.

> Network folder installations of this game are no longer supported.
>   Please move your game folder to a local drive, then try again.​ Error
>   Codes:
>
> BLZBNTAGT00000BC2

[Source](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/network-folder-installations-of-this-game-are-not-supported)

I haven't tested this, but you could as well try to map the shared drive to a folder instead using a symbolic link. I'm not sure, if the launcher accepts that one.

Command for this:
`mklink /d "c:\whatever\" "\\server\whatever\"`

(You need to have elevated rights and the local folder must not exist. It will be created by this command.)

Comment: I actually came into this one too, didn't work at first, but now I've created the link by running cmd.exe as admin. **Sadly, it didn't work**, WoW still detects unsupported drive. I think they might have been kinky and actually detect loading data speed of drive, that would explain that even through hard link it doesn't work ....

Comment: @jave.web thats strange... loading speed shouldn't be a factor, since a good raid and a 1 gig connection could easily outweigh a normal hdd. The launcher probably checks the system environment itself, but I doubt the blue posters will reveal their secrets.

Comment: The thing is the path is actually: NAS => regular "home" UTP => mini-switch => regular "home" UTP => router/switch => wifi => laptop . But I can play movies/TV series on laptop from the same NAS with no problem, even when downloading it at the same time ...

Comment: It might also just see that the hardlink actually goes to NAS, is there a way to trick it so it could not recognize that?